# Длина mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysql

Как узнать `lenght` или что - то другое, чтобы узнать кол-во массивов из `mysql_fetch_array`?
Например:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array){
echo $row['name'].''.$row['surname'];
}
```

Цикл выведет 3 человек. Как записать это кол-во в `<h2>Кол-во человек: <?php  ?></h2>`

Comment: Не используйте функции `mysql_*`, в PHP 7 их нет! **Книгу** по которой учитесь **выкиньте**! Вся документация с примерами тут http://php.net/manual/ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Количество человек: <?php echo mysql_num_rows($query);?>
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows работает также.

Comment: Чтобы использовать `mysqli_num_rows()`, нужно менять все функции на `mysqli_`.

Comment: зачем же менять все, можно сделать просто прослойку, в которой mysql_* будет вызывать mysqli_* ну и т.д. и подключить вначале. Если горит, такой вариант вполне подойдет для работы в 7